# Whats the proper way to use a proprietary software license according to ament_copyright?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm exploring ROS2, and I'm currently looking into unit testing.

I'm running the following commands,

```
colcon test
colcon test-result --verbose
```

I'm always getting a warning for a missing license:

```
test/test_something.py: copyright=My Company (2020), license=<unknown>
```

This is the header for my test_something.py file:

```
# Copyright 2020 My Company
# Proprietary License
```

Whats the proper text to include in the header for the warning to go away, for a Proprietary Software License? I've taken a look at the ament_copyright documentation but I didn't find an answer to my question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343351/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-a-proprietary-software-license-according-to-ament_copyright?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [ament_copyright/doc/index.rst](https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/dbc04bc412cba6b3e2c751c578f46ba3477e5c91/ament_copyright/doc/index.rst):

> The package uses Python entry points to get all list of known licenses and copyright holder. You can implement a custom package and contribute more implementations to these entry points or extend this package with more licenses.

It's rather terse, but that would seem to be the way to add custom licenses.

Using a separate package to host them and extend `ament_copyright` seems like a nice clean approach. Not sure what the runtime overhead of that would be though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-05**:
Python entrypoints are very low overhead. All the existing licenses are already entrypoints even for the "default" ones. As an example of what it takes to add a license see: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/pull/205/files including registering the entrypoint. That registration can be done from any python package in the workspace.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2020-02-05**:
Extending the package seems like a very good option for this use case, I'll give it a try and report on my findings.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2020-02-10**:
So I just experimented cloning the ament_copyright package to my workspace, added my proprietary license to ament_copyright (on my workspace) as suggested by Tully and it works beautifully. In my opinion this is a great solution for proprietary software.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-10**:
I believe the idea is to create a new package, host your files in there and then extend `ament_copyright` by registering an entrypoint with `ament_copyright`.

That would avoid you having to maintain a fork of the package while still being able to add the custom license check.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-10**:
Exactly what @gvdhoorn said. You should create your own package and export the entry point for ament_copyright to find. What you did to extend ament_copyright to support your package can be done in any python package you include in your workspace. I'd suggest a dedicated package `mycompany_ament_copyright`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The other choice is to simply not use `ament_copyright` if you are using a not supported license and don't want to provide an entry point for it (see https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/dbc04bc412cba6b3e2c751c578f46ba3477e5c91/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_package_hook.cmake#L15-L19 how to do that when using ament_lint_auto.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2020-02-05**:
That's definitely an option, thinking about it licensing is extremely relevant for open source software, maybe not so much on an enterprise environment. Still I'd rather have proprietary disclaimers on all files.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-05**:
I wasn't suggesting to drop the information from the files. I am suggesting not to use the linter.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2020-02-05**:
Yes I understood that, let me rephrase, I like having the information on the files thus I like the idea of having the tests looking for it.

**Comment by [frpunzalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50734/frpunzalan/) on 2020-03-10**:
@Dirk Thomas Can you give an example on how to exclude copyright linting in a python package. I was able to do it in a cpp package using the CMakeLists file but python packages don't have CMakeLists so I don't have an idea on how to do it.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-10**:
You must have a custom test which runs the linter since there is no "magic" provided by ROS to do so for you.

**Comment by [frpunzalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50734/frpunzalan/) on 2020-03-10**:
@Dirk Thomas You are absolutely right. Thanks. I didn't notice it earlier but the default package created by ROS2 create package contains a test directory with the test_copyright.py file. This must be the file that run the copyright lint.